# Page not Found on Subdomain Redirect to Main Domain 404?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have a mobile subdomain that does not have all the pages that the main domain does. I check to see if the user is on a mobile device and if they are send them to the mobile subdomain. The issue is sometimes the page does not exist on the mobile subdomain so I would like to keep them on the main site or redirect them back to the main site page if the page doesn't exist.

So basically I am looking to put something in the htaccess that if it is 404 send to the same page on the main domain.

Comment: Just curious, Why was this marked as off topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that files have same Path but different domains,

to redirect users to the main domain if a page is not found

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/%1
```

Comment: Yep that worked. Can you add something after the RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/%1?flag=blah ???

Comment: Actually Just noticed that it should be http://mysite.com/$1 and yes I was able to just add on http://mysite.com$1?flag=blah. Thanks Again